# How Do I Pass Later Defined Parameter Into PySpark SQL

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I defined a query like this:

```
    sql_query_1 = f"""
                select
                    Country_Name as country,
                    State_Name as state,
                    City_Name as city,
                    avg(Order_Rate)
                 from last_day 
                 where Country_Name  ='USA' and Account_ID = "{account_id}" 
                 group by 1,2,3;
            """

    for orders in order_list:
        account_id = orders["Account_ID"]
        spark.sql(sql_query_1)
```

In this case, it cannot find `account_id` as I only define the `account_id` in for loop which is executed later.

If I do a reverse way, it said it cannot find `sql_query_1` cause the for loop executed first and by the time it executing, `sql_query_1` hasn't define

```
    for orders in order_list:
        account_id = orders["Account_ID"]
        spark.sql(sql_query_1)

    sql_query_1 = f"""
                select
                    Country_Name as country,
                    State_Name as state,
                    City_Name as city,
                    avg(Order_Rate)
                 from last_day 
                 where Country_Name  ='USA' and Account_ID = "{account_id}" 
                 group by 1,2,3;
            """
```

I can embed the sql query into the for loop but is there any elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to pass the parameter to the sql string and instead of f-string I'm using .format() like so:

```
sql_query_1 = """
    select
        Country_Name as country,
        State_Name as state,
        City_Name as city,
        avg(Order_Rate)
     from last_day 
     where Country_Name  ='USA' and Account_ID = "{account_id}" 
     group by 1,2,3;
"""

for orders in order_list:
    account_id = orders["Account_ID"]
    spark.sql(sql_query_1.format(account_id=account_id))
```

Comment: sql_query_1 still executed first and name 'account_id' is not defined. I think this is an elegant way but seems not solve the problem

Comment: @JieZhang did you notice That I'm not using f-string formatting? what I mean by that is you need to remove `f` at the beginning of your sql query string

Comment: that's right, thank you so much!